# Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

i'm populating dropdownlist based upon the other dropdownlist..
When I select a value in the 1st dropdownlist i keep getting this error..

can someone explain it to me.. here's the code..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillCountry();
    }
}
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString());
    FillStates(CountryID);
    ddlCity.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int StateID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue.ToString());
    FillCities(StateID);
}

private void FillCountry()
{
    string strConn =      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CountryID, CountryName FROM Country";
    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    con.Open();
    dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
    con.Close();
    if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddlCountry.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryID";
        ddlCountry.DataBind();
        ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "No Countries found";
    }


}

private void FillStates(int countryID)
{
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT StateID, StateName FROM State WHERE CountryID =@CountryID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", countryID);
    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    con.Open();
    dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
    con.Close();
    if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddlState.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        ddlState.DataTextField = "StateName";
        ddlState.DataValueField = "StateID";
        ddlState.DataBind();
        ddlState.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "No states found";
    }
}

private void FillCities(int stateID)
{
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CityID, CityName FROM City WHERE StateID =@StateID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StateID", stateID);
    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    con.Open();
    dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
    con.Close();
    if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddlCity.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
        ddlCity.DataValueField = "CItyID";
        ddlCity.DataBind();
        ddlCity.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "No Cities found";
    }
}
}
```

i think my problem is the line here..

```
int CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

im using varchar datatype for all of my tables..

Comment: So `ddlCountry.SelectedValue` is not a valid `Int32`

Comment: CountryID column should be numeric

Comment: thanks for a quick reply.. but can you please elaborate it.. im new to c#..

Comment: @DorCohen but i cant change the datatype of my table CountryID.. any alternative line of code for varchar data type?

Comment: The problem is you're trying to parse a string value which *should* be in a valid `Int32` format and you're getting that exception because it's NOT in a valid format, i.e it is alpha/alphanumeric rather than numeric

Comment: There are many chances in your code that can cause this exception. Can't you put a break point and see from where the exception is being generated. It will be easy for diagnose then instead of being guessing.

Comment: This error will occur if the value of ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString() is non numeric or empty.

Comment: Can you tell us the value of ddlCountry.SelectedValue, when the error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the drop-down list value *isn't* a string representation of an integer.

While you *could* either use `int.TryParse` or (worse) a try/catch block, presumably the `SelectedValue` options are ones controlled by *you* rather than the user, so they *should* all be valid for whatever you're going to do with them.

The first thing to do is probably look at this in a debugger - when you get an exception (which should make the debugger break), what's the value that you're trying to convert? Once you've got the "bad value", work out how it got there.

EDIT: If you've got a value of "PRC0001" then that clearly *isn't* an integer. If you're using `varchar` in all your tables, then presumably your CountryID field is *also* a `varchar` - so why are you trying to convert to an integer in the first place?

Comment: @user1213269 there is no sample code. You`ll have to debug the application and see WHICH values your `DropDownList` holds. If you see non-numeric values there - *that's* your problem.

Comment: i've mentioned already that i am using a varchar as my datatype for CountryID.. is there any alternate code instead of that?

Comment: We didn't ask what's the datatype, we're asking what are the VALUES!

Comment: You can't convert `PRC0001` to an integer since it contains alpha characters. I think you`re lacking some basic knowledge and would advise you to do some further reading regarding C# before continuing with your problem

Answer (score -1):

This error will occur if the value of ddlCountry.SelectedValue.ToString() is non numeric or empty. Try putting this in try catch block.

Comment: look this guy has same intention.. :)